# Invoke a camera to start in Drupal 7 Forms API

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, camera, drupal-modules

I am currently developing a module which must be capable of taking a picture. I dont know how will I make it? How will I invoke a camera to open just by clicking a button? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/ooystein/1616836
ooystein's sandbox: Webcam field widget

This module provides a webcam field widget for the image field.
To use the module just add an image field to your content type and select the webcam field widget as the widget for the field.